# Exclude a page from a NavigationBar in Flutter/Dart

Tags: dart, flutter

I have set up my main.dart as a welcome screen with a login button and a search button, but I don't want the navigation bar to appear there.  I created a second file ("featured.dart") where I would like the navigation bar to begin, and for the rest of the pages on the app it will always be there (so, after you click away from the welcome screen, you will never see it again.  Check out the Spotify welcome screen for a good example). However, when I try to put my NavigationBar object inside a Scaffold starting on featured.dart aka not my starting page, the app crashes.  No error report or debug notice, and the code looks clean. What am I missing?

Here's the code for main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:chewie/chewie.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';
import 'featured.dart';
import 'profile.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

void main() => runApp(RambleApp());

class RambleApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Title",
      home: VideoBG(),
    );
  }
}

class VideoBG extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  VideoState createState() => VideoState();
}

class VideoState extends State<VideoBG> {
  VideoPlayerController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = new VideoPlayerController.asset('assets/Video.mp4');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Stack(
      fit: StackFit.passthrough, 
      children: [
        new ClipRect(
          child: new OverflowBox(
            maxWidth: double.infinity,
        maxHeight: double.infinity,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: new FittedBox(
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: new Container(
            child: new Chewie( //video player
              _controller,
              autoPlay: true,
              looping: true,
              autoInitialize: true,
              showControls: false,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    new Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          alignment: Alignment(0.0, -0.75),
          image: AssetImage('assets/title.png')
        ),
      ),
    ),
    new Container(
      alignment: new Alignment(0.0, 0.65),
        child: new Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Container(
              child: new FlatButton(
                child: new Text(
                  'TEXT ONE',
                  style: new TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                    fontSize: 17.5,
                  ),
                ),
                color: Color(0xFF70E0EF),
                shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(7.5)
                  ),
                onPressed: () {
                  _controller.pause();
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new FeaturedScreen()),
                  );
                },
              ),
              width: 150.0,
              height: 60.0,
            ),
            new Container(
              child: new OutlineButton(
                child: new Text(
                  'TEXT TWO',
                  style: new TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                    fontSize: 17.5,
                  ),
                ),
                borderSide: new BorderSide(
                  color: const Color(0xFF70E0EF), 
                  width: 5.0,
                  style: BorderStyle.solid,
                ),
                shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(7.5),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  _controller.pause();
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new ProfileScreen()),
                  );
                }, 
              ),
              width: 150.0,
              height: 60.0,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
  }
}
```

And here's the code for featured.dart, where I want the toolbar to start ("TEXT ONE" redirects to this):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'profile.dart';
import 'search.dart';
import 'favorites.dart';

class FeaturedScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Featured(),
      theme: new ThemeData(canvasColor: Color(0xffffffff).withOpacity(0.5)),
    );
  }
}

class Featured extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  FeaturedState createState() => FeaturedState();
}

class FeaturedState extends State<Featured>{

  int i = 0;
  var pages = [
    new FeaturedScreen(),
    new ProfileScreen(),
    new SearchScreen(),
    new FavoritesScreen(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      fit: StackFit.passthrough,
      children: [
        new Container(
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            image: new DecorationImage(
              image: new AssetImage('assets/FeaturedBG.png'),
              fit: BoxFit.cover
            ),
          ),
        ),
        new Scaffold(
            body: pages[i],
            bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
              items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: i==0?Icon(
                Icons.apps,
                color: Color(0xff70E0EF),
                size: 35.0,
              ):Icon(
                Icons.apps,
                color: Colors.black,
                size: 35.0,
              ),
              title: Text(
                'Collections',
                style: new TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 0.0,
                  height: 0.0,
                ),
              ), 
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: i==1?Icon(
                Icons.search,
                color: Color(0xff70E0EF),
                size: 35.0,
              ):Icon(
                Icons.search,
                color: Colors.black,
                size: 35.0,
              ),
              title: Text(
                'Search',
                style: new TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 0.0,
                  height: 0.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: i==2?Icon(
                Icons.favorite,
                color: Color(0xff70E0EF),
                size: 35.0,
              ):Icon(
                Icons.favorite,
                color: Colors.black,
                size: 35.0,
              ),
              title: Text(
                'Favorites',
                style: new TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 0.0,
                  height: 0.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: i==3?Icon(
                Icons.person,
                color: Color(0xff70E0EF),
                size: 35.0,
              ):Icon(
                Icons.person,
                color: Colors.black,
                size: 35.0,
              ), 
              title: Text(
                'Profile',
                style: new TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 0.0,
                  height: 0.0,
                ),
              ),           
            ),
          ],
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          currentIndex: i,
          onTap: (int index) {
            setState((){
              i = index;
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
  ],
);
  }
    }
```

Thanks!

UPDATE: Update.  I got rid of the "MaterialApp" instance in featured.dart as suggested by @RémiRousselet and replaced it with a Scaffold.  Now it still crashes but I have a backtrace:

```
W/MapperHal( 5503): buffer descriptor with invalid usage bits 0x2000
D/        ( 5503): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xebd088c0, tid 5633
F/libc    ( 5503): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0xd9002fec in tid 5592 (1.ui), pid 5503 (ample.rambleapp)
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'google/sdk_gphone_x86/generic_x86:9/PPP3.180510.007/4799589:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'x86'
pid: 5503, tid: 5592, name: 1.ui  >>> com.example.rambleapp <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0xd9002fec
    eax d7125400  ebx da2b4aac  ecx d7125400  edx d90ff970
    edi d9003090  esi d90030c0
    ebp d9003018  esp d9002ff0  eip d9a073ac
backtrace:
    #00 pc 009073ac  /data/app/com.example.rambleapp-YanUsKDV8Z_MFyb-cLaaAw==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #01 pc 0090a071  /data/app/com.example.rambleapp-YanUsKDV8Z_MFyb-cLaaAw==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #02 pc 0092ea7b  /data/app/com.example.rambleapp-YanUsKDV8Z_MFyb-cLaaAw==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #03 pc 00931eda  /data/app/com.example.rambleapp-YanUsKDV8Z_MFyb-cLaaAw==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #04 pc 00933533  /data/app/com.example.rambleapp-YanUsKDV8Z_MFyb-cLaaAw==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #05 pc 00933cd6  /data/app/com.example.rambleapp-YanUsKDV8Z_MFyb-cLaaAw==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #06 pc 006a8728  /data/app/com.example.rambleapp-YanUsKDV8Z_MFyb-cLaaAw==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #07 pc 0080a35c  /data/app/com.example.rambleapp-YanUsKDV8Z_MFyb-cLaaAw==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #08 pc 00698076  /data/app/com.example.rambleapp-YanUsKDV8Z_MFyb-cLaaAw==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #09 pc 0060371f  /data/app/com.example.rambleapp-YanUsKDV8Z_MFyb-cLaaAw==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #10 pc 0093089b  /data/app/com.example.rambleapp-YanUsKDV8Z_MFyb-cLaaAw==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #11 pc 00694bb4  /data/app/com.example.rambleapp-YanUsKDV8Z_MFyb-cLaaAw==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #12 pc 006a09e2  /data/app/com.example.rambleapp-YanUsKDV8Z_MFyb-cLaaAw==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #13 pc 006a0ba5  /data/app/com.example.rambleapp-YanUsKDV8Z_MFyb-cLaaAw==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #14 pc 0090986b  /data/app/com.example.rambleapp-YanUsKDV8Z_MFyb-cLaaAw==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #15 pc 008f69b2  /data/app/com.example.rambleapp-YanUsKDV8Z_MFyb-cLaaAw==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #16 pc 008e9b27  /data/app/com.example.rambleapp-YanUsKDV8Z_MFyb-cLaaAw==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #17 pc 008ffb73  /data/app/com.example.rambleapp-YanUsKDV8Z_MFyb-cLaaAw==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #18 pc 008ec080  /data/app/com.example.rambleapp-YanUsKDV8Z_MFyb-cLaaAw==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #19 pc 008f403e  /data/app/com.example.rambleapp-YanUsKDV8Z_MFyb-cLaaAw==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #20 pc 008e9af3  /data/app/com.example.rambleapp-YanUsKDV8Z_MFyb-cLaaAw==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #21 pc 008ebd38  /data/app/com.example.rambleapp-YanUsKDV8Z_MFyb-cLaaAw==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #22 pc 008f992f  /data/app/com.example.rambleapp-YanUsKDV8Z_MFyb-cLaaAw==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #23 pc 008ebd68  /data/app/com.example.rambleapp-YanUsKDV8Z_MFyb-cLaaAw==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #24 pc 008ef806  /data/app/com.example.rambleapp-YanUsKDV8Z_MFyb-cLaaAw==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #25 pc 008f0967  /data/app/com.example.rambleapp-YanUsKDV8Z_MFyb-cLaaAw==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #26 pc 009131ce  /data/app/com.example.rambleapp-YanUsKDV8Z_MFyb-cLaaAw==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #27 pc 0092ea84  /data/app/com.example.rambleapp-YanUsKDV8Z_MFyb-cLaaAw==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #28 pc 00931eda  /data/app/com.example.rambleapp-YanUsKDV8Z_MFyb-cLaaAw==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #29 pc 00933533  /data/app/com.example.rambleapp-YanUsKDV8Z_MFyb-cLaaAw==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #30 pc 00932cdb  /data/app/com.example.rambleapp-YanUsKDV8Z_MFyb-cLaaAw==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #31 pc 0092effa  /data/app/com.example.rambleapp-YanUsKDV8Z_MFyb-cLaaAw==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #32 pc 0000056b  <anonymous:d7840000>
Lost connection to device.
```

Final edit: I solved the problem.  The issue was that I was establishing the main.dart as the current page but making it impossible to define i as that page, so there was no way or page[index] to reconcile.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why do you have multiple `MaterialApp` instance ?

Comment: I thought that was the only way to establish the home element, which calls all my stateful widget functions.  Is that wrong?

Comment: @TrentKennelly Your "backtrace" is not a *Flutter* exception, i.e. not connected to the code you posted.

Comment: Two things - can you try removing the video part of the first screen and seeing it if still crashes? And also, can you tell us exactly when that crash happens? The reason I'm asking is that flutter doesn't generally cause itself to crash even if you do something slightly odd, so my first suspect is the video player plugin. Also, if you're able to provide us access to the source (including assets) that would simplify our debugging significantly =D.

Comment: Oh and which version of the video player plugin are you using? I just found this: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/commit/be9f4b66aa36608f71e443c370f9bfeed9596f51 - they've just fixed a bug that causes a crash on de-allocation which sounds suspiciously like what you're seeing.

Comment: @rmtmckenzie It happens when I click the TEXT ONE button (sorry for not mentioning that earlier).  The reason, I believe, is because of the transition logic for the navigation bar.  If I take out all page indexing for the BottomNavigationBar, I have no problem loading the page with the toolbar intact.  If I hot reload while in featured.dart having put the logic back in, the same crash happens.  I don't think it is the video player plugin (btw, the version is 0.4.0) because of the reasons previously stated.

Comment: I solved my problem.  Going to update above.

Comment: @TrentKennelly you should make an answer to your question with what solved it, that way people won't come across this thinking that it's not solved. Oh and BTW - using pages[i] for scaffold's body probably isn't the greatest idea - you're better off either making a new scaffold for each page (you could have that be a within a widget you share between the different pages if it's more or less the same) and pushing the new page using Navigator.push(...) each time. See the flutter [navigation tutorial](https://flutter.io/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics/)

Comment: @rmtmckenzie Thanks so much, I'll do that.  And I'll take a closer look at the navigation tutorial.  I see what you're saying about it not pushing.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. The issue was that I was establishing the main.dart as the current page but making it impossible to define i as that page, so there was no way or page[index] to reconcile. Thanks for the help!